# How do make /n used as a single character/symbol in python in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, substring

I am getting the substring of this string:

```
alpha = "*|^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,!-? "
```

I am using python 2.7.
My issue is when I want to input a second line in a string using /n and getting /n as a single substring

### My code:

```
alpha = "*|^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,!-? "
def main():
  intp = raw_input("Do you want to encode or decode a message? (Encode, Decode, Encode2, Makefile) ")
  if intp == "Encode":
    message = raw_input("What is the message you want to encrypt? ")
    encoded = keygen(message)
    print encoded
  if intp == "Decode":
    mes = raw_input("What do you want to decode? ")
    unen = unencode(mes)
    print unen
    #Get the first letter of a string
  if intp == "Encode2":
    bigmess()
  if intp == "Makefile":
    mfile()

def keygen(key):
  encode = []
  encode2 = ""
  for i in range(len(key)):
    ind = 0
    ind = alpha.index(key[i])
    ind=ind-3
    x = alpha[ind]
    encode.append(x)
  encode.reverse()
  return(encode2.join(encode))

def unencode(endmess):
  mess = []
  mess2 = ""
  for i in range(len(endmess)):
    inlist = alpha.index(endmess[i])
    inlist+=3
    mess.append(alpha[inlist])
  mess.reverse()
  return(mess2.join(mess))

def bigmess():
  str1 = ""
  list2 = []
  f= open("bigmessage.txt","r") 
  if f.mode == "r":
    cont = f.read()
    list2.append(cont)
  str1 = str(list2).strip('[]').strip('"')
  keygen(str1)



def mfile():
  f = open("bigmessage.txt", "w")
main()
```

Comment: The linebreak is not `/n`, it is `\n`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel yes i notice that but do you know any solutions?